# Lock for Promises chaining in Node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, promise, es6-promise

I have a REST API that does a sequence of asynchronous tasks one after another. The code looks like this:

```
asyncFunc1()
.then(asyncFunc2())
.then(asyncFunc3())
.then(asyncFunc4())
```

The first step will do some database query and the final step will update the database. Naturally (as I come from java/c++ background), I will add a lock at the beginning of my promises chaining to make sure the interaction with the database is protected.

But I am new to Node.js and its async processing on a single thread mode confused me here. So should I add one lock the beginning of my promises chaining or add locks at each step involving database action or I do not need a lock at all?

-------- update ---------

As one comment and an answer pointed it out I wrote my chain wrong (my actual code was correct though, just a sign indicating I am new to node.js :$)

```
  asyncFunc1()
  .then(asyncFunc2)
  .then(asyncFunc3)
  .then(asyncFunc4)
```

I actually use [Redlock](https://redis.io/topics/distlock) at the beginning of my chain and I am not sure if this is a good idea. The answer Rahul Singh provided said I do NOT need a lock!

Comment: What does the lock guard against?

Comment: First off, your chain is wrong.  It should be `asyncFunc1().then(asyncFunc2).then(asyncFunc3)`, etc...  Pass function references - don't call them first and pass the return result.

Comment: Single thread mode with purposely sequenced commands should not a DB lock for that sequence of code.  But, if there are other requests possibly running at the same time, then how you handle DB updates to avoid concurrency issues is entirely dependent upon what your code is doing and how the database works.  There is no generic requirement for a lock, but some things you might do with the DB like read something, modify it and write it back may need to be protected somehow from race conditions with other requests also using the database.

Comment: Hi, as you and another answer pointed it out, I wrote it wrong here (clearly a sign I am new to node.js :$ but my actual code is right as you said)

Comment: Hi I read somewhere and the answer I got from @Rahul Singh seems to say the then in promise may be able to handle it for me. That was actually the reason I raised my question in the first. Can promise/then really handle it? If they can how?

Comment: Using a promise chain will control the order in which your tasks run, for a single API call. It will not prevent other API calls from running at the same time and potentially modifying the same data. That's why I ask, what specifically is your lock meant to prevent? In general DB locking is something to avoid since it forces your API server to essentially behave like a single-threaded system - only one API call at a time will work. If you have 1000 users, things are gonna get slow quickly.

Comment: @stone I am afraid if one call has reached the step #4 and modified the database while another call reached the step#1 and read the old data.

Answer (score 0):

> when you create a promise using new Promise() it is invoked, so all
>   your function actually are executed as you create them and not when
>   you chain them.

Your chain function should be like

```
asyncFunc1().then(asyncFunc2).then()...
```

The asyncFunc1 should be a function returning a promise and not a promise itself.

Take a look a this [**article**](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) for more on Promises by Nolan Lawson

Comment: Yes, I wrote it wrong here (as a sign I am new to node.js :$ my actual code is right as you said)

Comment: @Qiulang In short you will not need a lock then in promises will handle that .

Comment: As another comment I got from @ jfriend00, my code does exactly "read something, modify it and write it back". I assume my REST API may be called at the same time so I added a lock.